# Does it hurt battery life to not fully charge and disconnect?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life

If I charge my device and let it charge not fully but say, 60% and disconnect,
does that hurt battery life?

If so, what are the 'safe' ranges?

Comment: Is this a newer device, less than 2 years old? If so, it is much less important to fully charge the battery as there is no "battery memory" like older devices. General rule of thumb though, try to stay above 20%, and charge to at least 80%.

Comment: May I point you to our nice [charging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info) for the answer(s) to your question(s) – even those charging questions you've not (yet) asked? :)

Comment: According to the Android AccuBattery app, charging to less than 80% is better than charging to 80%, so I wouldn't recommend charging that much unless you really need to.  Personally, I charge to 50-60%, unless I think I'll need more charge before I'm around a power source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Battery University. Battery level between 40 to 90 is recommended. Don't charge fully till 100%. Charge it till 90% and remove the plug. Then you will have long battery life.

Comment: Proper answers should give a reference for the information... and Battery University has a variety of answers on this topic depending on where you look... but it is an excellent reference. http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table is a great page. Although the 40 to 90 percent will allow for longest battery life, most batteries have a full charge cycle life of 300-500 full cycles (100%-0%-100%) but if you stay within the 50% window it will be around 1200-1500 charge cycles http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries.

Comment: I think this answer is close, but not completely accurate.  Charging it to 60% is much better than charging it to 90%, according to the Android AccuBattery app.