# Is it better to charge your battery above 50% or let it go down, technically speaking?

Tags: battery, charging, battery-life, hardware

Following up on [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144974/does-it-hurt-battery-life-to-not-fully-charge-and-disconnect):

Is it better, when the battery is at 40% to let it drop (use the phone until it's 30% for example) or to let it charge to 70%?

As far as I understand 50% is the "ideal" situation, but is it better to be "overcharged" or "undercharged" (for maximum life of the battery)?

Comment: Most modern devices have circuitry and software controls in place to prevent over charging, over discharge, and over cycling (that's a thing too). This has been talked to death and unless you are doing things that cause it to overheat, normal use isn't going to be improved much by any technique that limits deep cycling. Those days are largely past us. That said, you can increase your batteries longevity by following some basic rules, but honestly in modern phones the gain is minimal. https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries

Comment: Things have improved a lot since this question was addressed 5 years go... Today these things are much less of an issue, even the batteryuniveristy article linked above is kind of outdated. Due to how phones charge today, slowing the charge as battery level increases, the detriment to the lifespan of the battery is greatly reduced by going outside of the 40-90 percent range because of better technology and better batteries. I don't know anyone who recommends anything except "don't let your battery go completely dead" if you can avoid it, and even then once in a while is OK